# Is it ok practice to use a static class to collect common event handlers?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

In a Windows Forms app, there are some things I want various controls of the same type on different forms to always do upon certain events. For example, I want a single click on a DataGridViewCell that is a TextBox-type and is not read only to automatically enter edit mode. The simple event handler code, in this case on a form with a DataGridView called `dgvParms`, is:

```
private void dgvParms_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    DataGridViewCell c = dgvParms[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    if (!c.ReadOnly && c is DataGridViewTextBoxCell) {
        dgvParms.CurrentCell = c;
        dgvParms.BeginEdit(true);                
    }
}
```

I could easily move this method to a static class, say `CommonEvents`, and then on my individual forms' `Load` handlers assign the static method definition to the respective DataGridViews' CellClick event

```
this.dgvParms.CellClick += CommonEvents.dgvEditOnCellClick;
```

Is this acceptable or good practice? Or is it preffered to keep event handler logic with each consuming form's code? I could of course do something in between (but redundant) by defining local event handlers which then call the common method, such as

```
this.dgvParms.CellClick += (a, b) => CommonEvents.dgvEditOnCellClick(a, b);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks absolutely fine to me, although of course you will have to change you code to use the `sender` argument to locate the `DataGridView` that raised the event:

```
private void dgvParms_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    DataGridView dgvParams = sender as DataGridView;
    DataGridViewCell c = dgvParms[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    if (!c.ReadOnly && c is DataGridViewTextBoxCell) {
        dgvParms.CurrentCell = c;
        dgvParms.BeginEdit(true);                
    }
}
```

The general approach of changing or adding behaviour to a control by handling and reacting to its events is called an [attached behaviour](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx). It is most typically used in WPF, but there is nothing wrong with using it in WinForms too.

Comment: Make sure you check that `dgvParams != null` after the `sender as DataGridView` assignment.

Comment: @JasonDown this is not necessary, you can only assign this method to an event that passes a DGV as the sender argument. The way that events work means that this method will never be invoked with a null sender.

Comment: Force of habit... I guess it is only necessary to perform the check if the method parms were `(object sender, EventArgs e)`, which would mean anything could delegate the method as the event handler.

Answer (score 6):

You could try defining your own customized DataGridView by inheriting from DatagridView, and then adding this and any other specialized behaviors you need. I can't test the code below at this moment, but I believe it is correct:

```
public class MyDgv : DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnCellClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCell c = this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
        if (!c.ReadOnly && c is DataGridViewTextBoxCell)
        {
            this.CurrentCell = c;
            this.BeginEdit(true);
        }
    }
}
```

You may have some reason not to do this, but if you like this specific behavior in all of your dgv controls, just use your custom implementation.